# Azure data lake - External org app access - Authentication methods

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Say `organisation A` has an Azure data lake instance `DL1`. There are two containers in the `DL1` instance which are `container1` and `container2`. Now `app A` from `org B` has to access `container2` alone to drop files.

What are available authentication methods? Any sample code references with Azure Python or Java SDKs would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1210: use the compatible azure blob storage sdk**

You can use the `azure blob storage sdk` to create a `container sas token`, then the users only access to `this specified container` in ADLS Gen2.

**Note**: We can do that because the azure blob storage sdk is compatible with ADLS Gen2, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-supported-blob-storage-features#supported-blob-storage-features) for more details..

Take python for example, first of all, install [the latest azure blob storage package](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/).

Then use the code below to generate a `container sas token` which can be provided to `apps` in **org B**:

```
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas, ContainerSasPermissions, ContainerClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name ="your adls gen2 account name"
account_key="the key"
container_name="the container name"

sas_token = generate_container_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    container_name=container_name,
    account_key=account_key,
    permission=permission = ContainerSasPermissions(read=True,write=True,delete=True,list=True),
    expiry= datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)
)

#build the following container url of ADLS Gen2, then provide it to others to access the specified container.
sas_url="https://" + account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + container_name + "?" + sas_token

#when other users have this sas_url, they can use it to access the specified container.
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)

#for example, they can upload files to the container.
with open("D:\\test\\ttt.txt","rb") as data:
    container.upload_blob(name="test333.txt",data=data)
```

---

**Update 01: use ADLS Gen2 sdk**

You can create a `container sas token`, then provide the `container sas token` to others. So the others can use it to access the specified container only.

Here is an exmaple for python, please install the [azure-storage-file-datalake 12.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/) package first:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import generate_file_system_sas,FileSystemSasPermissions,FileSystemClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name ="ADLS Gen2 account name"
account_key="the key"
container_name="the container name"

#build account_url
account_url="https://" + account_name + ".dfs.core.windows.net/"

#generate the container sas token
sas_token = generate_file_system_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    file_system_name=container_name,
    credential=account_key,
    permission=FileSystemSasPermissions(read=True,write=True,delete=True,list=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)
)

#build the sas account url
sas_url = account_url + "?" + sas_token

#then we can provide the sas url to others, and they only allowed to access the specified container
container_client = FileSystemClient(sas_url,container_name)
file_client = container_client.create_file("c333.txt")
local_file = open("D:\\test\\ttt.txt",'rb')
file_contents = local_file.read()
file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))
file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

---

---

**Original answer:**

You can directly use the `account name` and `account key` of `ADLS Gen2` to authenticate. You can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python) for more details.

For example, you can nav to azure portal -> your Azure Data Lake Gen2 -> Access keys. From there, you can get account name and account key. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

For python, you can follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#connect-by-using-an-account-key) to build the authentication.

For java, you can follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java#connect-to-the-account).

Comment: I want to give access to only one container / file system not to the entire data lake or all containers

Comment: @Rag, I can think of 2 methods to do that. Please see the updated answer:).

Comment: thank you Ivan. programmatically both your snippets using DL/BStorage SDKs worked. The generated SAS URL with Azure Storage explorer does not work and asks for more permissions. sample error: `The SAS token has inadequate permissions. A list permission ('sp=l') is required`.

Comment: sure. do you know why the generated SAS strings would not work with desktop azure storage explorer app?

Comment: @Rag, I will take a look and update this answer later.

Comment: @Rag Just a quick test, it works fine at my side. When generate token, do you add the list permission? and for the endpoint, you should use `blob.core.windows.net` instead of `dfs.core.windows.net` to connect storage explorer. The last thing, you should use the latest version of storage explorer 1.16.0. You can see the updated section in my answer.

Comment: I am using `blob.core.windows.net`. I think it just means `list` permissions are required by storage explorer. Not sure how to generate that with the underlying class used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobsaspermissions?view=azure-python

Comment: @Rag, I'm using this package  azure-storage-file-datalake 12.2.0 package. And it has list permission like this `permission=FileSystemSasPermissions(read=True,write=True,delete=True,list=True)`. can you try with this package?

Comment: @Rag, figure it out, when using the blob storage sdk, we should use [ContainerSasPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containersaspermissions?view=azure-python) for permission, which has the list permission. Please see the latest updates in my answer.

Comment: yes, i also tried that recently and it worked. `permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True,list=True,write=True)`. when added in storage explorer, it appears under 'Local & Attached -> Storage Accounts -> (Attached Containers) -> <new entry>'

Comment: @Rag, glad that it's solved. can you please up-vote this answer? Thanks:)